# Azure Elastic job: could not find stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

Although I created the credential, login, target group & members against the right database; I keep getting an error when executing my SQL Server stored procedure.

Please note you cannot use 'USE' or prefix the database name.

I have the impression the stored procedure is eventually run against the 'master' database.

Please find some screenshots below.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Definitely, the `target_id` in the `job_executions` view suggests that you're connecting to the `master` database instead of the one containing your stored procedure.

Comment: isn't database_name a parameter to sp_add_jobstep? Or is it only for "normal" sql server, not azure

Comment: @AaronBertrand, i think that syntax isn't possible in azure, i seem to recall it being allergic to db.schema.procedure calls. One upside of using database name in step name is that it's easier to find out which databases various jobs ran against. It's harder to do if db names are embedded in the commands. But yeah, i usually do both belts and suspenders :)

Comment: @DaleK sorry about that, I took the view that the code in this specific case was not usefull. It's not that someone can replicate the situation easily. Anyway I'll take it into account for my next question. Thx
@ AlwaysLearning: this was indeed the problem, thank you!
The next problem is the following, been trying for hours to try to fix it. "Failed to connect to the target database: The server principal "job_credential" is not able to access the database "ion_PRD_mirror" under the current security context.  Cannot open database "ion_PRD_mirror" requested by the login. The login failed."